# How to implement Bernaola Galvan segmentation algorithm with matlab to complete time sequence segmentation

Tags: time-series, signal-processing

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GEsi.png)

I want to use the bg algorithm to remove the part of the processing data in the figure that tends to 0 (that is, the stage when the tool and the workpiece are not in contact), how to achieve this, or is there a better way to achieve it?

I hope this invalid data can be deleted, because there are many data curves like this, and it is too time-consuming to manually delete them. After consulting literature, I find that bg algorithm can realize my idea, but I do not know how to program it